# jquery flot, horizontal side by side and stacked chart not correctly working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

As shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg4ppsom/1) I almost have a working example of a horizontal side by side and stacked chart. Whats wrong with it? Does it have something to do with the way the data is formatted?

```
data: [
    [10, 1],
    [20, 2],
    [30, 3],
    [40, 4],
    [50, 5],
    [60, 6]
]
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest looking in the JavaScript console - you have a few errors there that will no doubt be causing this to not work.

Comment: BTW, in the fiddle you can't link directly to github `raw` files.  Change, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ to http://rawgithub.com/ and it'll work.  I fixed your link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of how you include the flot plugins.  `orderBars` changes the x values of the points so it must jitter the values before they get stacked.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.flot.js"></script>   
 <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
```

Updated and fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg4ppsom/2/).

Comment: You're a legend, Thank you.